# steam wont launch after driver update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, steam

recently acquired wolfenstein:the old blood in the steam sale and upon startup it recommended I update my graphics card driver.
I opened the device manager, updated my card, came back to steam and upon clicking play nothing happened.
I figured the update may require a restart so I restarted(didn't press the power button) and now when I start steam it validates the installation , connects the account and closes.
repeating this with task manager shows the application appearing and disappearing.

my setup:
2012 win7sp1
HP P7-1234
AMD ag-3650 apu currently on version 8.892.1.1000,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you updated your graphics driver from the control panel, and not from installing a driver package.

Start by installing the drivers by the manufacturer of your card. In this case, you'd be able to find them here: www.amd.com

Once those are installed and your system reboots, try to get into Steam again.

If it fails again, uninstall Steam, and then reinstall it.

That should resolve this.

Comment: attempting.  also reinstalling steam would be fun considering the size of the backup folder i'd have to make

Comment: I'd just move the steamapps folder out to a new directory. Reinstall steam, and then move the steamapps folder back in. Moving it will be instant.

Comment: doing it through the amd website worked but now i have a fake steam from AMD called raptor

Answer (score -1):

You can easily downgrade:

1. Go to device manager (search it in start menu or properties of my computer and it should be on your right)
2. Look for the drivers you installed

3.Open them up and click roll back changes or drivers